# Struts 1 form nested property doesn't resolve

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I'm working with a legacy system that runs struts 1.  Currently, I have nested action form classes like the following --

```
      public class GrandParentForm extends BasicActionForm {
        private ParentForm parentForm;

        public GrandParentForm ()
        {
          parentForm = new ParentForm();
        }
        //Typical getters, setters, populate, validate, reset methods
      }

    public class ParentForm extends BasicActionForm {
       private ChildForm childForm;

       public ParentForm()
        {
          childForm = new ChildForm();
        }
       //Typical getters, setters, populate, validate, reset methods
    }

    public class ChildForm extends BasicActionForm {
       private String childProperty;
       public ChildForm(){}
        //Typical getters, setters, populate, validate, reset methods

    }
```

Struts Config --  GrandParentForm is defined in here as a ActionFormBean,

```
    <form-beans.....>
      <form-bean name="grandParentForm" type="test.struts.action.pedigree.GrandParentForm " />
   </form-beans>
  <action-mappings ... >
    <action path="/test/path/preparePedigree"
       validate="false"
       scope="request"
       name="grandParentForm "
       input="/main/pedigree/PedigreeList.jsp"
       type="test.struts.action.pedigree.PreparePedigree">
      <forward name="success"
           path="/main/pedigree/PedigreeInformation.jsp" />
    </action>
 </action-mappings>
```

My question revolves around the evaluation of the properties of these forms via the struts tags on the front end.
If I use EL language -- ${GrandParentForm.parentForm.childForm.childProperty}
it will retrieve the appropriate value.

However for an input tag inside of a struts form element --

```
    <html:form .... >
      <input type="text" id="test_id" name="parentForm.childForm.childProperty"  .../>
    </html:form>
```

The name doesn't evaluate, it gets an empty parentform, childForm and then null childProperty.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem, in my struts-config.xml I have multiple action entries that use this form.  The final entry had scope session instead of request.  Once I changed it to request the properties get resolved successfully.